# duplicating 3 lines in sql server but changing the Period id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

On my web app in visual studio web forms I am creating, it is pushing and pulling data from a SQL Server database. I need help with a problem i have run into. On the rates page, is a gridview that displays the rates for the current period, there are 6 columns in total.

I need to put a button that would when clicked copy/duplicate the last 3 lines being Period_Id, Description, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4 . The problem is the period Id, for every 3 lines it is assigned 1 Id IE.

```
Period_Id, Description, Rate1,Rate2,Rate3,Rate4

1        , Example    , 7    ,  6  , 7   ,  0
1        , Example    ,8     ,  4  ,1    ,  100
1        , Example    ,8     ,  4  ,1    ,  400
```

When the lines are copied the Period_Id Must change but follow the sequence of 1,1,1 and become 2,2,2 when copied again become 3,3,3 and keep the other data associated to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have a `Primary Key` defined for the table.

Secondly, you can do this by following these steps.

1. Create a Stored Proc in SQL Server DB
2. Call the below Stored Proc from your Application.

`

```
Create Procedure CopyRates
@PeriodID INT
AS
BEGIN

   //Populate a temp table with all the values you want to copy from <YOURTABLE>
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Period_Id int, Description varchar(10), Rate1 int, Rate2 int, Rate3 int, Rate4 int)

INSERT INTO #TestData (Period_Id, Description, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4)
VALUES
(Select PeriodID, Descriptiom Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4)
From <YOURTABLE>
Where PeriodID = @PeriodID
)

   INSERT INTO <YOURTABLE> (Period_Id, Description, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4)
   SELECT Period_Id +1, Description,Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4
   FROM #TestData
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to insert this data into the table with just period_id being changed you can do a simple insert into with a select.

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Period_Id int, Description varchar(10), Rate1 int, Rate2 int, Rate3 int, Rate4 int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (Period_Id, Description, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4)
VALUES
(1,'Example',7,6,7,0)
,(1,'Example',8,4,1,100)
,(1,'Example',8,4,1,400)
```

Your insert statement would be something like this;

```
INSERT INTO #TestData (Period_Id, Description, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4)
SELECT Period_Id +1
,Description
,Rate1
,Rate2
,Rate3
,Rate4
FROM #TestData
```

And your results will look like this;

```
Period_Id   Description Rate1   Rate2   Rate3   Rate4
1           Example     7       6       7       0
1           Example     8       4       1       100
1           Example     8       4       1       400
2           Example     7       6       7       0
2           Example     8       4       1       100
2           Example     8       4       1       400
```